# Fastest browser for a minimal kiosk mode for Raspberry pi zero?

Tags: pi-zero, web-browsers

I need suggestion for a lightweight browser for kiosk mode for raspberry pi zero.
Chromium is running but it is a bit slow for my required application.
My application is just displaying scrolling text data from server port.

Comment: try a text based web browser like Lynx

Answer (score 4):

[Kweb](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=40860) would be a pretty good option for a kiosk as it was made for that purpose. [Midori](https://www.midori-browser.org/) also might work fine for you. You can look at this [MagPi article](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/raspberry-pi-browser-test) about different browsers on the Pi.  If you search you'll find websites with benchmarks of different browsers like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=260433).